# Optimizing aggregated output pig script

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to generate aggregated output.
What is the best way :

```
A_GROUP = GROUP A BY ID PARALLEL;
A_COUNT = FOREACH A_GROUP {
        A_TMP1 = FILTER A BY Col1 == 'Other';
        A_TMP2 = FILTER A BY Col2 == 'Other';
        cnt_fltrCol1 = COUNT(A_TMP1);
        cnt_fltrCol2 = COUNT(A_TMP2);
        GENERATE group,cnt_fltrCol1,cnt_fltrCol2;
}
```

Or :

```
A_FOREACH = FOREACH A GENERATE *, 
        ((Col1 == 'Other') ? 1 : 0) as fltrCol1, 
        ((Col2 == 'Other') ? 1 : 0) as fltrCol2;

A_GRP = GROUP A_FOREACH BY ID;

A_COUNT = FOREACH A_GRP {
            cnt_fltrCol1 = SUM(fltrCol1);
            cnt_fltrCol2 = SUM(fltrCol2);            
            GENERATE    
            group,cnt_fltrCol1,cnt_fltrCol2;
    }
```

Currently, I have memory problems (my real script is much bigger)
Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: first one is COUNT and second is SUM?

Comment: yes, but they're doing the same thing.

Comment: ...............................?